# How to replace a character at beginning and end of a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
path = "{'ResponseMetadata': {'Flag': 'Processed', 'Message': 'File Ingested successfully', 'INGEST_PATH': ['inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99', ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}
```

I would like to replace ' at the beginning and end of the strings only and not in middle of strings.

I am trying to make use of replace function of python to perform this task

```
path = path.replace("\'", "\"")
```

but above approach is replacing the ' every where in string and output obtained is

```
{"ResponseMetadata": {"Flag": "Processed", "Message": "File Ingested successfully", "INGEST_PATH": ["inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99", ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI"s Jan 2018.csv""]}}
```

but I do not want KPI's to get change to KPI"s, **one way which i can achieve this is to make use of replace function again like below to gain desired output**, but then problem with below approch is that I need to keep on adding replace with each new scenario and I would like to have generic solution can some one help here.

```
path = path.replace("\'", "\"").replace('"s', "'s")
```

Regards
Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend regular expressions.

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Regular_Expression

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

second link shows the regular expression language.

```
import re
path = """{'ResponseMetadata': {'Flag': 'Processed', 'Message': 'File Ingested successfully', 'INGEST_PATH': ['inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99', ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}"""

m=re.sub(r"'([^']*)'",r'"\1"',path)

print(m)
```

sub has the following signature: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

1. `"([^']*)"`  <== this is a group, because of () and accepts all signs except '
2. `'"\1"'` <== this is the replacer and will replace all founds with "(group)"

**result:**

```
{"ResponseMetadata": {"Flag": "Processed", "Message": "File Ingested successfully", "INGEST_PATH": ["inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99", ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}
```

Best regards

Comment: thanks for introducing me with regex pattern's in python. i will accept your one as correct answer as its a single line code which is able to perform the job

Comment: I hope it's reasonably understandable, otherwise we can talk about RegularExpressions again.

by the way:
Example: aaa7uzuzbbb  

text = "aaa7uzuzbbb"  
m = re.sub (r "(a {3}) (. *) (b {3})", r '\ 2', text)  

print (m) results in "7uzuz" because of aaa and bbb are markers now. This shows using more than 1 group

Comment: Thanks for lending extended help and providing more explanation, i am much clear on regex now. if any issues further i know where to reach now

Answer (score 0):

First, your string is invalid. So i'm defining it with triple quotes:

`path = """{'ResponseMetadata': {'Flag': 'Processed', 'Message': 'File Ingested successfully', 'INGEST_PATH': ['inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99', ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}"""`

How about iterating over the string's characters and checking the surrounding characters for `isalpha()`:

```
out = []
for ix, char in enumerate(path):
  # first make sure we have a surrounding character on each side
  if ix > 0 and ix < len(path):
    # now check for a quote and make sure that one of the surrounding characters are not letters
    if char == "'" and not (path[ix-1].isalpha() and path[ix+1].isalpha()):
      # if we find that case, replace the single quote
      char = '"'
  # add the character to the out list
  out.append(char)

# join all the characters back together
output = ''.join(out)

print(output)
```

Result (again, this is invalid to paste directly, unless it is triple quoted):

```
{"ResponseMetadata": {"Flag": "Processed", "Message": "File Ingested successfully", "INGEST_PATH": ["inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99", ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}
```

Comment: I don't think I understood an OP's question well but in your answer I can see quotes are changed everywhere

Comment: @Gad everywhere except here: `KPI's`

Comment: @JacobIRR: Thanks for sharing the solution, your solution works great, as it increases the code length and same job is done by one line code given by RoXTar i have marked his answer as best suited one in my case

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple attempt you can simply replace all and thereafter replace back the double quotes followed by letter s like the following

```
import re

path = '''
{'ResponseMetadata': {'Flag': 'Processed', 'Message': 'File Ingested successfully', 'INGEST_PATH': ['inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99', ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}
'''

path_ = re.sub('\'', '\"', path)
print(re.sub('\"s','\'s', path_))
```

output

```
{"ResponseMetadata": {"Flag": "Processed", "Message": "File Ingested successfully", "INGEST_PATH": ["inward/emr_batch/manual_cars/xy99", ""manual_cars/xy99/2020/08/12/145938/ABC KPI's Jan 2018.csv""]}}
```

you can target everywhere you want to replace like

```
print(re.sub('KPI\"','KPI\'', path_))
```

Comment: thanks for sharing a solution. but above solution does exactly what i have been doing by using iterative replace statements.